# Euclidean distance between each record with other records in an array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, euclidean-distance

so i have an array [n*m] and i need to code in c++ the Euclidean distance between each row and the other rows in the array and store it in a new distance-array [n*n] which every cell's value is the distance between the intersected rows.
distance-array:

```
   r0 r1 .....rn
   r0 0
   r1    0
   .       0
   .          0
  rn            0
```

the Euclidean distance between tow rows or tow records is:
assume we have these tow records:

```
 r0: 1 8 7
 r1: 2 5 3
 r2
 .
 .
 rn
```

Euclidean distance between r0 and r1 = sqrt((1-2)^2+(8-5)^2+(7-3)^2)
to code this i used 4 loops(which i think is too much) but i couldn't do it right, can someone help me to code this without using 3-D array ??
this is my code:

```
    int norarr1[row][column] = { 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 };
int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0;
for (i = 0; i < column; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < column; j++){
        sumd = 0;
       for (k = 0; k < row; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < row; l++) {
            dist = sqrt((norarr1[i][k] - norarr1[j][l]) ^ 2);
            sumd = sumd + dist;
            cout << "sumd =" << sumd << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
disarr[j][i] = sumd;
disarr[i][j] = sumd;
cout << disarr[i][j];
}       
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I suggest creating a `Point` or `Vector3D` class which holds the coordinates of each point/vector.

Comment: p.s. Your code is incorrect. You are calculating the sum of square roots, not the square root of the sum.

Comment: Also, `^` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. For now, let's ignore the for loops. We'll get to that later.

The first thing is that `^` is the bitwise exclusive or (XOR) operator. It does not do exponentiation like in some other languages. Instead, you need to use `std::pow()`.

Second, you are summing square roots, which is not the correct way to calculate Euclidean distance. Instead, you need to calculate a sum and then take the square root.

Now let's think about the for loops. Assume that you already know which two rows you want to calculate the distance between. Call these `r1` and `r2`. Now you just need to pair one coordinate from `r1` with one coordinate from `r2`. Note that these coordinates will always be in the same column. This means that you only need **one loop** to calculate the squares of the differences of each pair of coordinates. Then you sum these squares. Finally **after this single loop** you take the square root.

With that out of the way, we need to iterate over the rows to choose each `r1` and `r2`. Okay, this will take two loops since we want each of these to take on the value of each row.

In total, we will need three for loops. You can make this easier to understand by designing your code well. For example, you can create a class or struct that holds each row. If you know that every row is only three dimensions, then create a `point` or `vector3` class. Now you can write a function which calculates the distance between two points. Finally, store the list of points as a 1D array. In fact, breaking up the data and calculation in this way makes the previous discussion about calculating the distance even easier to understand.

Comment: Instead of `pow`, I would use `inline int sq(int v) { return v*v; }`

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Good suggestion. That would definitely be more efficient for this case.

Comment: thanx for your answer, yes i noticed i have many errors since i stopped programming long time ago.
i'll try your suggestion